# Find the center of SVG groups or shapes

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to position markers (circles) in the center of rooms on a SVG floor plan. Each room could be either a single shape - like a rectangle - or a group of shapes. The circle should cover about 1/4 of the room:
radius = (width + height) / 8

The svg needs to resize to its div container.[image]

After a lot of trial and error, I have come up with code that seems to work, but also looks overly complicated as I use getBBox(), getBoundingClientRect(), and matrixTransform():

- getBBox gives me the correct width and height, but x = y = 0 for group elements
- getBoundingClientRect + matrixTransform gives me the correct cx and cy coordinates, but not the correct room width and height.

Is there a simpler way?

```js
const draw = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

const NS = draw.getAttribute("xmlns");

// Get titles
const titleElements = draw.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS, "title");

Array.from(titleElements).forEach((titleElement) => {
  let parentElement = titleElement.parentElement;
  let clientRect = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  let bbox = parentElement.getBBox();

  let point = draw.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = clientRect.left + clientRect.width / 2;
  point.y = clientRect.top + clientRect.height / 2;

  // Convert screen coordinates into SVG document coordinates
  const svgP = point.matrixTransform(draw.getScreenCTM().inverse());

  // clientRect doesn't resize with the svg
  // let radius = (clientRect.width + clientRect.height) / 8;
  // bbox resizes with the svg
  let radius = (bbox.width + bbox.height) / 8;

  let circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");

  circle.setAttribute("cx", svgP.x.toString());
  circle.setAttribute("cy", svgP.y.toString());
  circle.setAttribute("r", radius.toString());
  circle.setAttribute("fill", "cyan");

  draw.appendChild(circle);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Floor Plan</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      viewBox="0 0 792 612"
      xml:space="preserve"
      color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
      class="st7"
    >
      <g>
        <g id="group1-1" transform="translate(659.691,-186.346) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1001</title>
          <g id="shape1-2">
            <rect x="0" y="508.5" width="90" height="90" class="st1" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="group1000-10" transform="translate(482.508,-114.75) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1000</title>
          <g id="shape1000-11">
            <rect x="0" y="208.5" width="90" height="90" class="st4" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="group1002-18" transform="translate(659.691,-67.0962) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1002</title>
          <g id="shape1002-19">
            <rect x="0" y="508.5" width="90" height="90" class="st5" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="0" y="208.5" width="90" height="90" class="st6">
          <title>Space.1004</title>
        </rect>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is basically correct. Either use `getBoundingClientRect()` and transform with `getScreenCTM().inverse()`, or use `getBBox()`, and transform with `getCTM().inverse()`.

Comment: The issue is that I am using getBoundingClientRect "and" getBBox, not "or". That's why I suspect there must be a better way. But if I try only one or the other, it fails.

Comment: your code assigns `bbox` but never uses it.

Comment: I have fixed the code and rephrased my question. Thanks @ccprog!

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer with the corrected code? I still don't see how it would work for a group.

Comment: ah. I see my error. `.getCTM()` gives the transform to the initial viewport, not the initial coordinate system. Then the best way is really to move the circle inside the transformed group, as per Paul's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that's a bit simpler.

```js
const draw = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

const NS = draw.namespaceURI;

// Do the rooms that are groups
let rooms = document.querySelectorAll("title + g");
rooms.forEach(room => {
  room.appendChild( makeDot(room.getBBox()) );
});

// Do the rooms where the title is in a rect
let titles = document.querySelectorAll("rect > title");
titles.forEach(title => {
  let rect = title.parentElement;
  rect.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', makeDot(rect.getBBox()) );
});


// Make the circle element
function makeDot(roomBounds)
{
  let radius = (roomBounds.width + roomBounds.height) / 8;
  let circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", roomBounds.x + roomBounds.width / 2);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", roomBounds.y + roomBounds.height / 2);
  circle.setAttribute("r", radius);
  circle.setAttribute("fill", "cyan");
  return circle;
}
```

```html
    <div id="app" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      viewBox="0 0 792 612"
      xml:space="preserve"
      color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
      class="st7"
    >
      <g>
        <g id="group1-1" transform="translate(659.691,-186.346) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1001</title>
          <g id="shape1-2">
            <rect x="0" y="508.5" width="90" height="90" class="st1" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="group1000-10" transform="translate(482.508,-114.75) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1000</title>
          <g id="shape1000-11">
            <rect x="0" y="208.5" width="90" height="90" class="st4" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="group1002-18" transform="translate(659.691,-67.0962) rotate(60)">
          <title>Space.1002</title>
          <g id="shape1002-19">
            <rect x="0" y="508.5" width="90" height="90" class="st5" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="0" y="208.5" width="90" height="90" class="st6">
          <title>Space.1004</title>
        </rect>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to have dedicated code for groups. Would the code for rect work with any shape? As mentioned in my question, rectangle is just an example. I could have polygons, paths, etc.

Comment: Yes. But note that it will put the dot in the centre of the shapes' *bounding box* - not the centre of the shape.  If the path or polygon has an oddly shaped contour, then the dot may ebd up outside the shape.  Finding the optical centre of an arbitrary shape contour is a much more complex task.

Comment: Also, insertAdjacentElement might be an issue for me as the plan could have multiple layers and I need the dots on top of everything. But I get the idea.

Comment: That might be a problem then. The reason I am inserting them where they are is so that they are affected by any `transform`s there might be on ancestor elements.  If you need to insert them on a completely separate layer, elsewhere in the SVG, then you'll need to apply a comparable transform to the circle somehow.

Comment: Right, that's what I was doing in my original code. The main takeaway from your code for me is to separate groups from shapes.